# OpenERP 7 - Can't install report_aeroo_ooo due to missing python dependencies (Uno)

Tags: odoo, openoffice.org, openerp-7, pyuno

I can't install report_aeroo_ooo in OpenERP 7 because there are some unmet python dependencies concerning the uno modules.

Apparently, new versions of OpenOffice and LibreOffice come with a uno version for python 3 so you can't use it with python 2.7.

I've researched a lot, tested a lot and tried older versions of OpenOffice with no success.

I'm not a big expert in python. Is there any way we can use a python 3 module in python 2.7?

Or has anyone been able to overcome this?

Comment: have you tried below answer ? if you solve your problem than accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to download `uno Package` From below command this will solve your problem.

`sudo apt-get install python-uno`